# "Function" is not a type C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a template class and pass it a compare function. I found a great answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512705/passing-compare-function-for-a-generic-class)

Unfortunately when I made a template class called "WaitingQueue" and passed the compare function in the constructor of the class(in class foo), the code does not compile and throws error: "'compare' is not a type".

I cannot understand the error here. The code in the link above runs without error. Can anyone please tell me what I have done wrong here? Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { OK, ERROR };


template <class T>
class WaitingQueue
{
   struct QueueElement
   {
      public:
      T                   data;
      QueueElement       *next;

      QueueElement(T *pdata): next(0)
      {
          memcpy(&data, pdata, sizeof(T));
      }
    };

    QueueElement *head, tail;

    public:
    bool (*comparefunc)(uint16_t, T*);
    WaitingQueue (bool (*compareFunction)(uint16_t, T*)) :comparefunc(compareFunction), head(0), tail(0) { }

  int search(int16_t id, T *ret_data)
  {
      QueueElement *temp = head;
      QueueElement *prev = 0;

      if (temp != NULL)
      {
          if (comparefunc(id, &temp->data) == true)
          {
              if (prev)
              {
                  prev->next = temp->next;
              }
              else
              {
                 head = head->next;
              }

              memcpy(ret_data, &temp->data, sizeof(temp->data));
              delete temp;
              return OK;
          }
          prev = temp;
          temp = temp->next;
      }
      return ERROR;
  }
};

typedef struct _cmd
{
  uint8_t flags; 
  uint16_t id; 
} cmd;

bool compare(uint16_t id, cmd *cmd)
{
    return (cmd->id == id);
}

class foo
{
   WaitingQueue<cmd> queue(compare);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you will have to extract a [mcve] (formatted consistently) also be report the actual errors (see also the links given).

Comment: Narrow your code example to a [mcve] please. There's a lot of irrelevant code to just reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to the error: `memcpy(&data, pdata, sizeof(T));` That's a red flag. Don't do copies of types that way. If `T` is a non POD type you'll getta lot into trouble.

Comment: Unrelated to the error. Why don't you use `lambdas` and `std::function`?

Comment: @KunalPuri: `std::function` with current-day compilers kills inlining pretty much always and adds layers of indirection, I wouldn't want to use it in a comparison functor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the usual vexing parse. `WorkingQueue<cmd> queue(compare);` is understood by the compiler as the declaration of a method named `queue` returning a `WorkingQueue<cmd>` and taking an object of the nonexistant type `compare`. You can make it understand that you mean to declare a *field* initialized with the `compare` function by using braces initialization:

```
WaitingQueue<cmd> queue{compare};
```

Comment: @AbdullahKhalil: great, consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted then. :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers